# mongod libstdc++.so.6 no such file or directory

Tags: mongodb, fedora, libstdc++

I have installed mongodb-org and mongodb-org-server, but when I start it I got the error below:

> mongo: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My env is Fedora 25. In the following way I checked that libstdc++ provides libstdc++ and I installed it, but the error remains.

```
# yum whatprovides libstdc++.so.6
Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf whatprovides libstdc++.so.6' (see 'man yum2dnf')

Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:08 ago on Sat May 13 16:15:59 2017.
libstdc++-6.2.1-2.fc25.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
Repo        : fedora

libstdc++-6.3.1-1.fc25.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
Repo        : updates
# yum install libstdc++
```

Did I done something wrong?

Comment: Where did you install the `mongodb-org` from? It does not look like Fedora 25 package.

Comment: Thank you for your remind. I checked `/etc/yum.repos.d` and found that I am using a wrong .repo file. The error disappears after changing my configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you installed version for different Fedora release or for RHEL. The numbers matter since they are build against different libraries versions and they might not be compatible.

Per comments, check the repo file in`/etc/yum.repos.d/` and make sure you have chosen the correct repository.